# How to track google doc file name change history?

Tags: excel, google-drive-api, google-docs

> I created a google doc file and shared with my team.
>
> After some day I see the file is not there,I crosscheck my all file
>   after that I found the data in one sheet, someone changed the name.
>
> How I come to know who change the filename.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Go through the below step you get to know all the change the name of any
>   google file and all activity related to the specific file

Step 1: Login with your google account(Where your file stored)

Step 2: Go to google [drive](https://drive.google.com/drive)(https://drive.google.com/drive)

Step 3: Click on the right side i(Info icon)[image: google-drive-file-info]

Step 4: Search for the target file and select it.

Step 5: Click on the left side activity tab and see all the activity
                              [image]